# Custom Widget: Error inflating class

Tags: android, xml, widget

I want to adjust the Filter options of the AutoCompleteTextView, since it does not recognise spaces in between. That's why I created a class called MyAutoCompleteView:

```
package my.house;

public class MyAutoCompleteView
   extends
      android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView
{

   public MyAutoCompleteView (android.content.Context context)
   {
      super (context);
   }

   public MyAutoCompleteView(android.content.Context context, android.util.AttributeSet attrs)
   {
      super(context, attrs);
   }

   public MyAutoCompleteView(android.content.Context context, android.util.AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
   {
      super(context, attrs, defStyle);
   }
}
```

To test this thing, I changed my layout xml to:

```
<my.house.MyAutoCompleteView
    android:id='@+id/search'
    android:layout_height='wrap_content'
    android:layout_width='fill_parent'
    android:singleLine='true'
  ></my.house.MyAutoCompleteView>
```

I'm inflating the layout file since I use Fragments.

Here's the onCreateView Method in my Fragment:

```
@Override
   public android.view.View onCreateView (
      final android.view.LayoutInflater inflater,
      final android.view.ViewGroup container,
      final android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {

      return inflater.inflate (my.house.R.layout.myfragment, container, false);
}
```

Unfortunatly I'm getting this error message:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class my.house.MyAutoCompleteView

Any ideas what the problem might be? Thanks!

Comment: remove `xmlns:android='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'` from my.house.MyAutoCompleteView

Comment: thanks you for your comment! I removed the line - no change. Still: "Error inflating class"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

proguard unfortunately optimised my code and reduced it by the constructor. Proguard disabled and it works.